# command from terminal input and output will save an assigning directory

Tags: python-3.x

### In command line, I want to give python hist.py -n 1000 -o /dir and output will be png in the assigning directory. Can anyone help on it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
import os, sys, errno


def plotData(outputDir):
        outFilename = "hist.pdf"
        outFilepath = os.path.join(outputDir)

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("-n","--number", help="display a square of   a given number",type=int)
        parser.add_argument('-o', '--outputDir', required=True,
                    help='The directory to which plot files should be saved')
        
        args = parser.parse_args()
        num=(args.number)
        outFilepath=(args.outputDir)
# example data
        mu = 100  # mean of distribution
        sigma = 15  # standard deviation of distribution
#num=input()
        x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(int(num))

        num_bins = 50
        # the histogram of the data
        n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, normed=1,  facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
        # add a 'best fit' line
        y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)


        plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--')
        plt.xlabel('Smarts')
        plt.ylabel('Probability')
        plt.title(r'Histogram of IQ: $\mu=100$, $\sigma=15$')

  # Tweak spacing to prevent clipping of ylabel
        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
        plt.savefig (outFilepath,outFilename)  
        plt.show() 
        plt.close()
```

I could give random variable but not directory from terminal command line.

I have used args.outputDir but it does not work for me.
and i am learners

Comment: This question is just about getting the variables from `argparse`? `args.outputDir`  gives the output directory.

Comment: You said _I could give random variable but not directory from terminal command line_ ... so I was curious why you don't sue the output directory from args. I think we need a better description of what goes wrong in your progam.